# AngularJS bind and replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-model

I am new to AngularJS and I am struggling with this.I am using MVC 5 to create a form.

I have an input text where people enter some text (Note the ng-model):

```
          <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 21, @placeholder = "Elegi un titulo atractivo...", ng_model = "Title" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Then i have this peace of html where I want to show what the user wrote, but I want to replace the " " space character with "-" I am seeing in real time the text being written there but how to replace those characters?

```
        <small >www.site.com/article/<span id ="shareLink">{{Title}}</span></small>
```

If the user types "How to train your dragon" the ouptup in the {{Title}} should be: "How-to-train-your-dragon"

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I checked the answer, but is managing concepts that I cant grasp, I will try to spagetti code that to see if that works :)

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Any help instead of finding something similar?

Comment: I made it work using your reference. Thanks!